# Index not updated within a transaction when INSERTing data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, transactions

I have a transaction that executes in READ COMMITTED isolation level. Within the transaction I insert 10,000 rows into a table called 'Docs' with DocId as primary key and 3 indexes on VendorId, CompanyId and ProgramId. However, it appears that the indexes do not get updated till I commit data. Is this true? Is there a way I can force indexes to be updated within the transaction before the commit is called?

Comment: What do you have to substantiate this belief?

Comment: I agree with Damien: why do you think they are not updated?

Comment: A query Q1 within the transaction is taking a very long time after I add many records to one of the tables  'CustomerDocs' in the join. When I have very few records in 'CustomerDocs' then inserting many rows does not slow down the query Q1. So I guess Q1 is doing a table scan, which takes longer if index is not there for rows inserted within same transaction.

Comment: I found the problem. My query Q1 was using a column in one of the inner joins and there was no index existing on this column. Hence it was doing a table scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true (unless the indexes are disabled). 
The uncommitted index updates will only be available in READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level or with the nolock hint.

Why would it be a problem? Do you really need to see the uncommited data? Read uncommited is usually used to avoid the locking overhead not to read the new data.

Comment: For the index to be available within same index, do I still need to run the transaction in READUNCOMMITED mode?

Comment: Sounds like you don't know if it is using the indexes. View the execution plan to see if it is. Ctrl+M in SSMS before executing the query.